# Laravel storage auth check

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have to download some files from my webapp with laravel 5.6 and I am using the local storage.

I have my routes like `downloads/{file}` with the auth middleware and it's working properly.

The storage url is the default from laravel www.myweb.com/storage/files/ ...

the thing is if I use the route `www.myweb.com/downloads/foo.pdf` the controller is working properly and i must be logged in to download the file
but if I access from `www.myweb.com/storage/files/foo.pdf` I can see the file without being logged in

How can i solve this? should i create another controller or route to handle this?

should i create a route like

```
Route::get('/storage/files/{file}', 'FilesController@download')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score -1):

`/storage/files` is already actual path of the storage. to avoid conflict change your route to other path

```
Route::get('/storage/files/{file}', 'FilesController@download')->middleware('auth');
```

change to (sample)

```
Route::get('/files/{file}/download', 'FilesController@download')->middleware('auth');
```

then do your logic in `FilesController`

Comment: This is what I already have. I need to restrict the /storage/files/....